# is it possible to read key inside another key in the property file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i am using spring framework & messageSource & PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to deal with property files 
and i want to so something like the following ?

```
key.num1=value1
key.num2= i am using ${key.num1}
```

in a key read the value of another key.
how to do so ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. According to the below text from [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer's JavaDoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)

> PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer checks simple property values, lists,
>   maps, props, and bean names in bean references. Furthermore,
>   placeholder values can also cross-reference other placeholders, like:
>
> rootPath=myrootdir
>   subPath=${rootPath}/subdir